# Roll the die... play again?

Tags: python, game, python-3.x

Is there a way to write this code more efficiently so that it is easier to read, maybe using loops and lists?

```
import random
total = 0
sixes = 0
fives = 0
fours = 0
threes = 0
twos = 0
ones = 0
limit = 50
throws = 0
Total = 0

play = input("Do you want to play, 'Y' or 'N'")
if play.upper() == "Y" :
    play = True
else :
    play = False


while total < limit and play :
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    throws +=1
    total += roll
    if roll == 6:
        sixes +=1
    elif roll == 5:
        fives +=1
    elif roll == 4:
        fours +=1
    elif roll == 3:
        threes +=1
    elif roll == 2:
        twos +=1
    elif roll == 1:
        ones +=1
    else :
        print(" try again ")

if play :
    print("Total throws : ",throws)
    print("Total : ",total)
    print("Total 6's : ",sixes)
    print("Total 5's : ",fives)
    print("Total 4's : ",fours)
    print("Total 3's : ",threes)
    print("Total 2's : ",twos)
    print("Total 1's : ",ones)
else :
    print("Yr los")
```

Comment: Could you please add some more context to your post, like what your code does, and if there is anything *specifically* that you would like assistance with?

Answer (score 6):

Your program is quite static,
and as you probably know that's not good.

First I would recommend changing the entire `throws`, `ones`, `twos`, etc logic to a list.

```
# Lazily initialise it with 6 zeros
throws = [0] * 6
```

This will now be where we hold `ones`, `twos`, etc but not `throws` or `total`.

The way you should use it is by indexing it.

```
if roll == 6:
    throws[5] += 1
elif roll == 5:
    throws[4] += 1
# etc
```

As you can probably guess, you can just index it with `roll - 1`.
And that is right! Below is most of your old code in a few lines.

```
total = 0
throws = [0] * 6
while score < limit and play:
    roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    throws[roll - 1] += 1
    total += roll
```

Now all there is to look at is your `print`s.
You can use `str()` to convert a number to a string.
And so you can automate most of your prints.

```
for side, amount = enumerate(throws, 1):
    print('Total ' + str(side) + "'s:", amount)
```

First `enumerate` will loop through the list, giving you the index and item.
Or in our case `side` and `amount`.
The above `print` looks kinda ugly, and so you can change the print to use `str.format`.

```
print('Total {}\'s: {}'.format(side, amount))
```

This replaces the first `{}` with the value of `side`, and the second `{}` with `amount`. So if `side` was 1, and `amount` was 2 it would display `Total 1's: 2`.

In summery, your code will look something like this:

```
import random

if input("Do you want to play, 'Y' or 'N'").upper() == "Y" :
    play = True
else :
    play = False

limit = 50

total = 0
throws = [0] * 6
while score < limit and play:
    roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    throws[roll - 1] += 1
    total += roll

if play :
    print("Total throws : ", sum(throws))
    print("Total : ", total)
    for side, amount in enumerate(throws, 1):
        print('Total {}\'s: {}'.format(side, amount))
else:
    print("Yr los")
```

To further improve your program I would recommend that you put all the 'play' functionality into a function and make your program work with any sized dice.

```
def play(limit, size):
    total = 0
    throws = [0] * size
    while score < limit:
        roll = random.randint(1, size)
        throws[roll - 1] += 1
        total += roll

    print("Total throws : ", sum(throws))
    print("Total : ", total)
    for side, amount in enumerate(throws, 1):
        print('Total {}\'s: {}'.format(side, amount))

if input("Do you want to play, 'Y' or 'N'").upper() == "Y" :
    play(50, 6)
    play(500, 20) # Limit = 500, dice size = 20
else:
    print("Yr los")
```

Comment: You forgot to index with `roll - 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Using idiomatic set-comprehension and `Counter` makes this so much shorter and clearer:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import random
>>> throws = (random.randint(0, 5) + 1 for _ in range(10000))
>>> Counter(throws)
Counter({3: 1696, 5: 1683, 1: 1663, 6: 1658, 2: 1654, 4: 1646})
```

Further improvement over this would be extracting the number of sides and the number of throws into a constant, writing a user interface, allowing multiple dices to be thrown at once and summing them, printing more human-friendly output, extracting a `roll_die` function ...